# Program to replay sounds

Tags: sound

I am looking for something simple...but I can not find it.
I need a simple program the plays prerecorded sounds when pressing a key. For example:

- I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, it will play the X1 sound file
- I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, it will play the X2 sound file

etc.

Do you have something in mind?

Comment: See `man paplay`...

Comment: do you know any with user interface? thanks

Comment: You do not need that. A program with a user interface cannot be bound to a shortcut key.

Comment: ok lets omit the shortcut key function. just plain buttons where the user can bind sound files on them. thanks

Comment: For some reason `paplay` doesn't play mp3 files for me. However, the `play` command from the `sox` package works fine.

Comment: and if `play` doesn't work, you could always use `mplayer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `play` command to play files from the command line.

First, install the necessary packages:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install sox "libsox-fmt*" libsox3 libsoxr0 libsoxr-lsr0 lame
```

Then, use the `play` command to play a file.

For example, if I have a file named `sound1.mp3` in my user's `~/Music` directory, I can use the following command to play the file:

```
play ~/Music/sound1.mp3
```

Go to Settings > Keyboard > Custom Shortcuts and set a custom shortcut to use your command. Do not use a shortcut that is already in use or it will not work. After you are finished, be sure to log out and log back in.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and the same for any F key will not work. These shortcuts are already in use.

However, you can use something like:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> instead or something like

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or with any other number key will probably work.